# Looking for a tutorial on creating SharePoint masterpages as solutions in Visual Studio

Tags: master-page, solution-package, custom-masterpage

I am looking to build some SharePoint masterpages for 2010 and deploy them as WSP solutions to my various SharePoint environments.  Are there any good tutorials out there on building a VS solution for master pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post describes how to create a module in a SharePoint project to include a custom master page as well as how to set it as the master page upon deployment: http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2010/03/26/deploying-a-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: It looks like this tutorial just covers creating the solution to contain the masterpage.  What about actually designing it?  Is there an editor like you have in Designer?

Comment: No, you can only edit the master pages in the code view in Visual Studio.  You could use SharePoint Designer to do the design work on the master page and then just copy and paste the code over to Visual Studio.  Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: Ok.  Thx for the info.